# Xcode warning "Property access results unused - getters should not be used for side effects"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

I'm getting this warning when I'm calling a local routine.

My code is this:

```
-(void)nextLetter {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    currentLetter ++;
    if(currentLetter > (letters.count - 1))
    {
        currentLetter = 0;
    }
    self.fetchLetter;
}
```

I'm getting the warning on the self.fetchLetter statement.

That routine looks like this:

```
- (void)fetchLetter {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    NSString *wantedLetter = [[letters objectAtIndex: currentLetter] objectForKey: @"langLetter"];

    NSString *wantedUpperCase = [[letters objectAtIndex: currentLetter] objectForKey: @"upperCase"];    


.....   
}
```

I prefer to fix warning messages, is there a better way to write this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The dot notation (i.e. `self.fetchLetter`) is meant for properties, not for arbitrary methods. The `self.fetchLetter` is being interpreted as "get the 'fetchLetter' property of 'self'," which isn't what you intend.

Just use `[self fetchLetter]` instead.

Comment: This workaround no longer applies in Xcode 6.3 (beta)

Comment: I mean calling the selector instead of using dot notation. It technically shouldn't have probably made a difference, and now Clang still treats it the same way. @DarkDust's answer actually expresses the semantic intent of calling a selector just for its side effects

Comment: @Dov That is certainly true for property accessor methods (such as `[UIViewController view]`), but this question doesn't involve those. Still, I guess it's useful to know for the people who arrived here by googling the error message.

Answer (score 13):

In newer Xcode versions, even the `[object method];` may trigger the warning. But sometimes we actually do need to call a property and discard the result, for example when dealing with view controllers and we need to make sure the view is actually loaded.

So we were doing:

```
// Ensure view is loaded and all outlets are connected.
[self view];
```

This now also triggers the *“Property access results unused - getters should not be used for side effects”* warning. The solution is to let the compiler know it's done intentionally by casting the result type to void:

```
(void)[self view];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring fetchLetter using syntax like this?

```
@property (retain) id fetchLetter;
```

That looks wrong for what you're doing. Properties are intended to be variable accessors that (in the case of getters) don't have any side effects.

You should declare fetchLetter as a method, like so:

```
- (void) fetchLetter;
```

and access it using:

```
[self fetchLetter]
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I did declare fetchLetter as you suggest. I have now changed the declaration to [self fetchLetter] as you and Tom indicated.. I appreciate the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I just got my problem resolved, in my case a CoreLocation Project, using both answers from Tom and Chris -

I declare:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

And implemented like:

```
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;
....
- (void) dealloc {
         [self locationManager];
}
```