# How to add a UIActivityIndicator View in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

I don't know how to explain but... If you understand me when I say a "loading circle" perfect, I just want to do this

```
    // Start loading in the middle of the screen frozing all interaction
    for (int c = 0; c < ([barcos count] - 1); c++)
    {
        NSArray *datos = [[barcos objectAtIndex:c] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
        NSString *nombreImagen = [datos objectAtIndex:2];
        NSURL *accesoFtp = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",urlFtp,nombreImagen]];
        NSData *imagen = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:accesoFtp];
        [imagen writeToFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Barcos/%@",nombreImagen]]] atomically:NO];
    }
    // Stop frozing all interaction and remove the loading circle
```

Probabbly I have to add a thread or something but I don't know how to do what I want exactly I hope you can help me, again. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

activityIndicator.startAnimating;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        for (int c = 0; c < ([barcos count] - 1); c++)
        {
            NSArray *datos = [[barcos objectAtIndex:c] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            NSString *nombreImagen = [datos objectAtIndex:2];
            NSURL *accesoFtp = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",urlFtp,nombreImagen]];
            NSData *imagen = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:accesoFtp];
        [imagen writeToFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Barcos/%@",nombreImagen]]] atomically:NO];
        }

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating;
    });
});
```

Two things

```
 1.- The activity indicator is too small but works, if I can to it bigger or same size but make darker the background would be better (Thanks!)
 2.- I have a warning with startAnimating and stopAnimating "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects"
```

Thanks =)

Comment: There should be a built in object for this, IIRC.

Comment: I was asking because I didn't know what was the controller name :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using [**MBProgressHUD**](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Also check this code:

```
//Show your activity indicator here

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    for (int c = 0; c < ([barcos count] - 1); c++)
    {
        NSArray *datos = [[barcos objectAtIndex:c] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
        NSString *nombreImagen = [datos objectAtIndex:2];
        NSURL *accesoFtp = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",urlFtp,nombreImagen]];
        NSData *imagen = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:accesoFtp];
        [imagen writeToFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Barcos/%@",nombreImagen]]] atomically:NO];
    }
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              //hide that activity indicator here
            });

});
```

**EDIT:**

Never call methods like:

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating;
activityIndicator.stopAnimating;
```

These are used for calling setters and getters.

Change it to:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: That's more complex of what I want, I think the activity indicator is enough, right?

Comment: Midhun, He is asking about UIActivityIndicator!!

Comment: @rokimoki: Ya, you need activity Indicator. I fixed your issues. Please check the edited answer

Comment: BTW @MidhunMP If I touch a button "while loading" this will do the IBAction assigned (change to other screen) but I need load before do anything because is the updated data to use the App.

Comment: @rokimoki: When you displaying the activity set your view's userinteraction to no and after dismissing set it to YES.

Comment: Done and tested, thanks a lot, I'm learning a lot with u :) xd

Comment: @rokimoki: with pleasure :) Good Luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a UIActivityIndicatorView.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];
```

Also, like shown by Midhun MP, you may have to use asynchronism to, for example, load data while your indicator is showing.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try Activity Indicator.

Comment: to start animating, use [activityIndicator startAnimating]; and to stop animating, use [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [svprogresshud](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the style of activityindicator,

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

use any of these styles.

And This link can help to solve your second issue 
[xCode "Property access results unused - getters should not be used for side effects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346682/xcode-property-access-results-unused-getters-should-not-be-used-for-side-effe)

SOLUTION:
instead of using `activityIndicator.startAnimating;` and `activityIndicator.stopAnimating`
use `[activityIndicator startAnimating];` and `[activityIndicator stopAnimating];`

Comment: A question cannot have multiple answers! One that fills all your requirements can be accepted as the real answer! Your choice

Comment: All answers helped and I feel very helped in this page I vote up those who helped me and I select the "main" answer the most completed answer for my question. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the size of the activity indicator:

```
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 80.0);
activityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.75, 1.75);
```

By the way, if you are populating a tableview, you may consider enabling the user interaction at the same time you launch the activity indicator:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and restoring it after:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```